# Is it possible to run a command as root without password and entering sudo?

Tags: sudo, root

Suppose I have  a user `some_user` and command `/usr/bin/command`.
How can I execute this command as root by entering `/usr/bin/command`, but not `sudo /usr/bin/command`?

I tried to edit `sudoers` with `visudo`, but without success, password is not prompted, but I need to write `sudo`:

`some_user ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/command`

Is there any difference between above command and `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/kill` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to understand your question more clearly; Do you mean for e.g running an application (while being root) but As another user,  without to type the password For-this-user ?

Comment: I want to run a command as root (being another user), without entering sudo. /usr/bin/command, not sudo /usr/bin/command.

Comment: Okay understood; You have (in visudo, sudoers)  access to SUDO privs On  some_user,  correct?  (Not only it's "NOPASSWD" but, the privs too) ?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make `/usr/bin/command` setuid root. However, this will work for ALL users and not only the particular one. Ie. any user who types `/usr/bin/command` will run the command as root, without the need to specify a password - you cannot restrict this to particular users only. Also, when you set `/usr/bin/command` setuid root, there will be no possibility to run this command as non-root until you remove the setuid bit.

Btw. that's exactly how `sudo` works - `/usr/bin/sudo` is setuid root, so it automatically becomes root when you type `sudo`. If it weren't setuid root, it won't be able to switch to root.

But I suggest you don't set random commands setuid root. `sudo` was designed to use that way and it makes many security checks before actually let you run the command. **By definition**, if you type a command name in the terminal, you are running that command as your current user ID (unless the command elevates privileges by itself, eg. by being setuid root, or using `sudo` internally as in Tony's solution). `sudo` is there to clearly distinguish command being run as non-root from command being run as root. Therefore you shouldn't omit it.

Comment: You could make a copy of the command, then `chown` the copy to `root` and a group created specifically for that purpose,  `chmod` the copy to `-rwsr-x---`, and make all users that should be allowed to use the command members of that group. This is how Ubuntu allows normal users to run wireshark, for example. But note this might open security holes if the command that's getting run is not intended to work that way; for example, if the command allows you to specify a file name to read or be written to, it'll be able to read/write **every** file on your system.

Comment: @GuntramBlohm Note for safe file reading, you need to fork, and then drop privileges (by switching to the real user) in the child before opening the file. Don't just drop privileges in the master process and switch back, or you could get unwanted privilege escalation, like in the recent Ubuntu exploit

Answer (score 5):

Probably easiest to write a wrapper script.
New script at `/usr/local/bin/command` that runs `/usr/bin/command` via sudo

**/usr/local/bin/command**

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "[I] Invoked by '${USER}', running as root" >&2
sudo /usr/bin/command $(printf '%q ' "$@")
```

Comment: `"$@"` will already pass the parameters properly. Actually, you are overescaping them. If you passed `"he'llo"` as parameter, command will receive `he\'llo`

Comment: This can also be done by using an alias, at least in tcsh.  E.g. I have "alias shut 'sudo systemctl poweroff'" in my .tcshrc file, and the "NOPASSWD: option for those commands in the sudoers file.  I think this is cleaner than having a separate wrapper script.

Comment: Most installs will already just accept `poweroff` by itself, no need for the extra words.

Comment: Furthermore, `$(printf '%q ' "$@")` will actually do nothing to help with whitespace. If the arguments are `aa` and `bb cc`, the output will be `aa bb\ cc`, which gets split to the three arguments `aa`, `bb<backslash>`, `cc`. (with a real backslash, but the comment formatting messes it up.) **Quotes don't work after expansions**, and the same goes for backslashes which `%q` is so fond of using.

Comment: An `alias` might also work, in the same vein as this answer.